# Laravel api bypass auth api for specific ip address

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Below is my laravel 8 api route and middleware that I use

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth:api', 'StripScript'],'prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
    Route::get('/list', [ListController::class, 'list']);
});
```

I this I want to bypass middleware 'auth:api' if I get request from specific ip address so user doesn't require to pass token and it should auto login as one specific user.

Note that I want to bypass auth and not to do 'Ip address Whitelist' as I do have whitelist for this I want to totally by pass for one IP address.

Comment: i would say don't do that, it's a very bad idea, there is no reason for a client to not authenticate itself

Comment: these api are used for internal server app also which don't require authentication

Comment: That's not really a valid reason, you should not trust a request because it came from an internal ip, and be aware that ip spoofing is a thing, the attacker will not get the response, but he could submit data without authentication

Answer (score 1):

It's not good idea, But any way if you want try this...

Go `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`

Add && override `handle` function like below

```
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {

        // check $request is coming from where and set a statement ture/false for a $isComingFromDesiredIp;

        if (! $isComingFromDesiredIp) {
            $this->authenticate($request, $guards);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => in_array(request()->ip(), $arrayOfTrustedIps) ? ['StripScript'] : ['auth:api', 'StripScript'],'prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
    Route::get('/list', [ListController::class, 'list']);
});
```

You should also handle the references to the authed user, if there are any (e.g. auth()->user()->id will throw an error).

IMHO you should authenticate the trusted party via a token sent in header, if you have access to the api call code.
Managing these kind of exceptions in your code can quickly become cumbersome and will be challenging to understand for everyone (including you).